# How to add an overlay to a AVPlayer?

Tags: ios, objective-c, avplayer

I want to play a video in `AVPlayer` but want to open the `AVPlayer` in a `UIView` so that I can add a overlay on it.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];


    UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeSystem];
    [button setTitle:@"Play" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [button sizeToFit];
    button.center = CGPointMake(320/2, 60);
    [button addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonPressed:)
     forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [self.view addSubview:button];
}

-(void)buttonPressed:(UIButton *)button
{
    NSURL *urlVideoFile = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:@"https://www.rmp-streaming.com/media///bbb-360p.mp4"];
    NSAssert(urlVideoFile, @"Expected not nil video url");

    _playerViewController = [[AVPlayerViewController alloc] init];
    _playerViewController.player = [AVPlayer playerWithURL:urlVideoFile];
    _playerViewController.view.frame = self.view.bounds;
    _playerViewController.showsPlaybackControls = YES;
    [self.view addSubview:_playerViewController.view];
    self.view.autoresizesSubviews = YES;
}
```

It's playing the video in a player, but I want to open the video in a `UIView` so that I can add the overlay on it.

Comment: You just need to add "addSublayer" instead of "addSubview".

Answer (score 0):

Take IBOutlet of Your UIView for Example

```
IBOutlet UIView *videoView;
```

And Call this method

```
-(void)buttonPressed:(UIButton *)button
{
   NSURL *videoURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:filePath];
   AVPlayer *player = [AVPlayer playerWithURL:videoURL];
   AVPlayerLayer *playerLayer = [AVPlayerLayer playerLayerWithPlayer:player];
   playerLayer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspect;
   playerLayer.frame = videoView.bounds;
   [videoView.layer addSublayer:playerLayer];
   [player play];
   player.actionAtItemEnd = AVPlayerActionAtItemEndNone;

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                          selector:@selector(playerItemDidReachEnd:)
                                             name:AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTimeNotification
                                           object:[player currentItem]];
}

- (void)playerItemDidReachEnd:(NSNotification *)notification
{
   AVPlayerItem *p = [notification object];
   [p seekToTime:kCMTimeZero]; 
}
```

Comment: @shiwani If an answer solves your issue you should indicate that your question is solved by clicking the checkmark to the left of the answer.